# What does the function state_fidelity() do in Qiskit?

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I am trying to solve a system of linear equation using HHL algorithm in Qiskit. I have a problem with understanding the purpose of the following function.

```
state_fidelity()
```

To understand this I have followed their official [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/terra/quantum_circuits.html). But it is not clear to me yet.

They used this function like the following code.

```
from qiskit.quantum_info state_fidelity, process_fidelity

backend_sim = BasicAer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
result = execute(circ, backend_sim).result()
state = result.get_statevector(circ)
print(state)

state_fidelity(basis_state('0110', 4), state)
```

The last line of this code generates this output.

**1.0**

Please, help me understand this.

Comment: it computes the quanum state fidelity. See e.g. [this question on quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6733/55)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

State fidelity is the measure of how close two quantum states are to eachother ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states)). So what the last line of the code is trying to do is to see how close the resulting state is to the state `'0110'`. A fidelity of `1.0` means the states are exactly the same, so the variable named `state` in the code is a state vector that corresponds to the state `'0110'`.

The exact definitions can be seen from the wikipedia page, or the [code for the function](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/quantum_info/states/measures.py).

Comment: Thank you. Now concepts are transparent to me.